# How to get List of test classes and associated errors in salesforce

Tags: apex

In my Organization some classes are failing ,
How to get List of test classes and associated errors?

Comment: Go to developer console or Apex test execution page and run all test classes. You'll get to know which are getting pass/fail.

Comment: How to get the List of failed classes as excel sheet...???

Comment: refer below answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. I don't say it is a standard way but it's a workaround to achieve it.

**Step 1**: Run all test classes from Apex Test Execution page and click on View test history:

[image]

**Step 2**: Copy page by page all rows:

[image]

**Step 3**: Paste it in your excel sheet:

[image]

Once you've all data you can apply Filter on columns and get failed test classes. That's it and you're done..!!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Its possible .
As Salesforce is having object for everything in the same way we do have a object called "ApexTestResult". So all the test class run details will be stored in that object. 
So we can run a query on that object as per the requirement like as followed.

Query :

```
SELECT ApexTestRunResultId, ApexClassId, Message, MethodName, Stacktrace, TtestTimestamp
FROMApexTestResult WHERE Outcome = 'fail'
```

Here we can fetch the error message associated with failed test class along with the stack trace.In fact we can use "testtimestamp" in where clause to more specific on the desired result.

For more info, see the thee documentation on [`ApexTestResult`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/sforce_api_objects_apextestresult.htm)

Answer (score 0):

For Apex Test Failures: Setup->Deployment Status->Deployment Status->Failed->View Details